# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined" after fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

Getting this error after including the catch block.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined.

```js
    const fetch = require("node-fetch");
    function update(){
      fetch("http://api.coronatracker.com/v3/analytics/dailyNewStats?limit=200").then(response=>response.json()).then(rsp=>{
          console.log(rsp.data)
          rsp.data.forEach(element=>{
            lat=element.lat;
            lon=element.lng;
            cases=element.daily_cases;
            if(cases>255){
              color="rgb(255,0,0)";
            }
            else{
              color="rgb(${cases},0,0)";
            }
            new mapboxgl.Marker({
              draggable:false,
              color:color
            }).setLngLat([lon,lat]).addTo(map);
          });
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
```

Comment: Where does `console.log(rsp)` show?

Comment: That means you're are not looping over array, forEach is an array method

Answer (score 0):

`response.json()` returns object without any wrapper. So it's present in `rsp` not in `rsp.data`.
So just remove `.data`

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
function update() {
  fetch("http://api.coronatracker.com/v3/analytics/dailyNewStats?limit=200")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((rsp) => {
      rsp.forEach((element) => {
        lat = element.lat;
        lon = element.lng;
        cases = element.daily_cases;
        if (cases > 255) {
          color = "rgb(255,0,0)";
        } else {
          color = "rgb(${cases},0,0)";
        }
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}

update()
```

Comment: Please, just telling someone to do something is not enough. Please explain why that works.